# What is the difference between method m () and m.render () ？　m.render() is always required?

Tags: mithril.js

`m()`  makes `virtualDom`?

`m.render()`  makes `realDom`?

That means `m.render()` is always required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much! From the [m() documentation](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.html) on the Mithril site:

> This is a convenience method to compose virtual elements that can be
>   rendered via `m.render()`.

There are other ways to display stuff than `m.render()` however, with the help of components. A summary from the [m.component() documentation page](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.component.html):

> There are three ways to render a component:
>
> - `m.route` (if you are building a single-page application that has multiple pages)
> - `m.mount` (if your app only has one page)
> - `m.render` (if you are integrating Mithril's rendering engine into a larger framework and wish to manage redrawing yourself).